# React Native TensorFlow issue

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build an app which that classify an image. To do this I use TensorFlow. I took this codes from [Image Classification on React Native with TensorFlow.js and MobileNet](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/image-classification-on-react-native-with-tensorflow-js-and-mobilenet-48a39185717c)

But when I try to click "Tap to choose image" button, I got nothing. Here is my code:...................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'
import { fetch } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native'
import * as mobilenet from '@tensorflow-models/mobilenet'
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions'
import * as jpeg from 'jpeg-js'

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
  isTfReady: false,
  isModelReady: false,
  predictions: null,
  image: null
}
getPermissionAsync = async () => {
  if (Constants.platform.ios) {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!')
    }
  }
}
imageToTensor(rawImageData) {
    const TO_UINT8ARRAY = true
    const { width, height, data } = jpeg.decode(rawImageData, TO_UINT8ARRAY)
    // Drop the alpha channel info for mobilenet
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 3)
    let offset = 0 // offset into original data
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 3) {
      buffer[i] = data[offset]
      buffer[i + 1] = data[offset + 1]
      buffer[i + 2] = data[offset + 2]

      offset += 4
    }

    return tf.tensor3d(buffer, [height, width, 3])
  }

classifyImage = async () => {
  try {
    const imageAssetPath = Image.resolveAssetSource(this.state.image)
    const response = await fetch(imageAssetPath.uri, {}, { isBinary: true })
    const rawImageData = await response.arrayBuffer()
    const imageTensor = this.imageToTensor(rawImageData)
    const predictions = await this.model.classify(imageTensor)
    this.setState({ predictions })
    console.log(predictions)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

selectImage = async () => {
  try {
    let response = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3]
    })

    if (!response.cancelled) {
      const source = { uri: response.uri }
      this.setState({ image: source })
      this.classifyImage()
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
  async componentDidMount() {
    await tf.ready()
    this.setState({
      isTfReady: true
    })
    this.model = await mobilenet.load()
    this.setState({ isModelReady: true })

    // add this
    this.getPermissionAsync()
  }

  render() {
    const { isTfReady, isModelReady, predictions, image } = this.state

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle='light-content' />
        <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.commonTextStyles}>
            TFJS ready? {isTfReady ? <Text>✅</Text> : ''}
          </Text>

          <View style={styles.loadingModelContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Model ready? </Text>
            {isModelReady ? (
              <Text style={styles.text}>✅</Text>
            ) : (
              <ActivityIndicator size='small' />
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.imageWrapper}
          onPress={isModelReady ? this.selectImage : undefined}>
          {image && <Image source={image} style={styles.imageContainer} />}

          {isModelReady && !image && (
            <Text style={styles.transparentText}>Tap to choose image</Text>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.predictionWrapper}>
          {isModelReady && image && (
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              Predictions: {predictions ? '' : 'Predicting...'}
            </Text>
          )}
          {isModelReady &&
            predictions &&
            predictions.map(p => this.renderPrediction(p))}
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <Text style={styles.poweredBy}>Powered by:</Text>
          <Image source={require('./assets/tfjs.jpg')} style={styles.tfLogo} />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#171f24',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  loadingContainer: {
    marginTop: 80,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  text: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontSize: 16
  },
  loadingModelContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 10
  },
  imageWrapper: {
    width: 280,
    height: 280,
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: '#cf667f',
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 10,
    position: 'relative',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10
  },
  predictionWrapper: {
    height: 100,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  transparentText: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    opacity: 0.7
  },
  footer: {
    marginTop: 40
  },
  poweredBy: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#e69e34',
    marginBottom: 6
  },
  tfLogo: {
    width: 125,
    height: 70
  }
})

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Pressing that button won't do anything unless isModelReady is true. This is happening in componentDidMount(). Maybe you have to wait some time until the model is ready. Without some logs is hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks for interest! I'm waiting to see that model ready is checked on the screen, after that I press the button but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I added to top this:

`import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'`

and solved issue.